# SCR "current gain" - calculating gate resistance

Tags: triac, thyristor, scr

Trying to understand the SCR. Have made this outlay which I shall find the right resistors for.

edit
[image: experiments]

or

[image: experiments]

The SCR is a [TYN1225](http://datasheet.octopart.com/TYN225RG-STMicroelectronics-datasheet-8330392.pdf)

But since I have found it difficult to understand \$I_{GT}\$ and \$V_{GT}\$ I have begun with this outlay. That is, after I had understood \$V_{GT}\$ I began with this setup and realize now that there was a relationship between the load consumption and \$I_{GT}\$

edit

[image: #2 layout]

Discovered that at the voltages/current I attempted with that there was a gain on around 480, which I only became more confused about.

If I have to make the first layout to be ha max 10A out, then \$I_{GT}\$ should be about 21mA. From this calculation

$$ {10\text{A}\over480\text{ "hFE"}} = 0.02083\text{mA}$$

Do not assume that this "gain" is the same at the different currents (not examined) and do not seem to see anything in the datasheet which gives me an explanation of the relationship between the load and \$I_{GT}\$

Is there such a relationship I can relate to?

Why do I think of limiting the \$I_{GT}\$ opposed to choosing the resistance to max \$I_{GT}\$ As a extra security if it can be done. For example, if I do not want the output to exceeded, lets say 2A, if I then restricts the \$I_{GT}\$, will this not cause the gate not to open if the current exceeds 2A?

The second I'm confused about is the calculation of the resistance.

If I relate to \$I_{GT}\$ = 20mA and \$V_{GT}\$ = 2V

$$ {240\text{AC}\over2\text{periods}} = 120\text{V}$$

$$ 120\text{AC} \times 1.41\text{ } = 169.2\text{peak}$$

$$ 169.2\text{V} - 2\text{V} = 167.2\text{V}$$

$$ {167.2\text{V}\over2*20\text{mA}} = 4.18\text{KΩ}$$

but

$$ 167.2\text{V} \times 2*20\text{mA} = 6.688\text{W}$$

seems to be to much.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't quite understand what hfe has to do with SCR, but one thing is wrong here, that SCR needs a pulse trigger and not a constant current on the gate.

Comment: why I have put it with quotation marks, but there is still a current gain. It is there, on the other side of the optocouplers.

Comment: The thyristor in your CircuitLabs schematic is upside-down. I don't understand your question but you seem to think that there is a "current gain" in an SCR. That's not how they work. You trigger them and they turn on and stay on until the current falls below the hold-on threshold.

Comment: Marko Buršič - If you refer to #2 layout, it was only for testing to understand the V/IGT.

Comment: transistor - Yes happened a few errors in the bottom layout. Try to read what I have written and you will understand what I  assume. Know, but to tricker them you need to have a certain current which depends on the load, gain as mentioned.

Comment: Simply ensure that Igt > 40mA and the load current is > 90mA and you will be fine. Igt is needed to trigger the SCR after SCR is turn on (Iload > Ih) Igt is not needed and can be 0A.

Comment: G36 - #2 layout I made in different setups, first with a load which was smaller but big enough IH and here I could trigger the at 4mA, by greater load should the gate also have greater IGT. Is it not equal to max IT = max IGT (gain)?

Comment: Please tell us if you understand that the SCR is not a current amplifier. It is a current switch.

Comment: I do....... :'(

Answer (score 1):

As everyone told you the SCR is not a current amplifier as a bipolar transistor. It is a latch-up component; put enough current on the gate and it will switch on, and it will remain ON until the load current is more than Ih (holding current)

Graph from wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thyristor

[image: Voltage-current versus Ig]

Comment: I know, try to understand what is written or create the trial and see

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear about SCR operation ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffG8bL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. The SCR transistor equivalent.*

- When the gate voltage, at G, rises enough to forward bias the B-E junction of Q2 its collector-emitter resistance will decrease.
- This will result in a small current being drawn from the base of Q1. As Q1 turns on its collector current will feed into the base of Q2 assisting the gate current.
- This additional base current into Q2 is a form of positive feedback. Q1 and 2 will turn hard-on with each driving the other's base.
- The trigger signal at G can now be removed and the device will remain in conduction. It should be clear that the only way to switch it off is to drop the current to zero somehow. In a mains-supplied circuit this occurs on every negative half-cycle.

To conclude, it is not normal to consider this a current amplifying device. No matter what the \$ h_{FE} \$ of the transistors is the device will turn hard-on when an adequate trigger is supplied. The SCR current is then only limited by the source and the thermal characteristics of the device. You can't partially turn it on with, for example, half the recommended trigger current.

You *can* turn it on part way through the mains cycle to give phase control of the voltage and this has *the effect* of varying the AC but in fact it is fully on or fully off with the ratio of the times determining the average current.

---

\$ I_{GT} \$

> *JustMe*: I began with this setup and realize now that there was a relationship between the load consumption and \$I_{GT}\$.

This is incorrect. \$I_{GT}\$ does not control the load in any proportional way.

There is an excellent 240 page and very readable document by ON Semiconductors, [Thyristor Theory and Design Considerations
Handbook](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/HBD855-D.PDF) and on page 5 they define \$I_{GT}\$ as

> The maximum value of gate current required to switch the
>   device from the off−state to the on−state under specified
>   conditions. The designer should consider the maximum
>   gate trigger current as the minimum trigger current value
>   that must be applied to the device in order to assure its
>   proper triggering.

On page 10 under *Basic Behaviour* you will read (emphasis mine):

> Observe that if current is
>   injected into any leg of the model, the gain of the
>   transistors (if sufficiently high) causes this current to be
>   amplified  in another leg. In order for regeneration to
>   occur, it is necessary for the sum of the common base
>   current gains (α) of the two transistors to exceed unity.
>   Therefore, because the junction leakage currents are
>   relatively small and current gain is designed to be low at
>   the leakage current level, the PNPN device remains off
>   unless external current is applied. When sufficient trigger
>   current is applied (to the gate, for example, in the case of
>   an SCR) to raise the loop gain to unity, **regeneration
>   occurs and the on−state principal current is limited
>   primarily by external circuit impedance**. If the initiating
>   trigger current is removed, the thyristor remains in the on
>   state, providing the current level is high enough to meet
>   the unity gain criteria. This critical current is called
>   latching current.

Comment: I know all that and nor is it my 2 questions. Think outside the box. One question put another way: why is Igt only referred as max?

Comment: "_I know all that and nor is it my 2 questions._" OK, but it's not clear from the question you _have_ asked. "_Why is Igt only referred as max?_" Because that's what's required to guarantee that the device turns on. There is no point in specifying a minimum.

Comment: Will have to say no because max IGT depends on the load. Understand your thinking because you only think of it as a switch, but as I have touched in my questions, this should also be a way where you can put a limit on it, so you are sure that it does not open if the load is too large, but not tested yet.

Comment: Should hopefully be the case that when IT max, IGT also is max.

Comment: Else, the second question, which resistor would you say is ok if we relate to 40mA per SCR in the #1 outlay, thinking also watt wise?

Comment: Your questions and comments are very confusing. "_Will have to say no because max IGT depends on the load._" Why do you think that IGT depends on load? Where did you read this?

Comment: Nothing I've read, but as explained you begyndte my forsøger Just Because I could not understand Vgt or Igt as this is never nämnde. Vgt you snabbt found out why you started on Igt to figure this out and here I saw quick at de higher the current load the Greater Igt, and since I do not know the term of this, you nämnde "hFE". Assumed att the reader knew what I meant. IT and Igt max, is from the most logical assumption that 40mA is Igt max, at full load, IT max.

Comment: And I know that under normal circumstances, I had to choose Igt to max to secures that it trigger but can you see what I mean by that to limit it as a security? Assuming that Igt 40mA which is max by IT max, but if I only need to use half of IT max, which therefore also is half of Igt, then why not, it safer?

Comment: You should be thinking of _reliable operation_ - not safety. You need 40 mA to turn on the SCR no matter what the load is. Small load: ≥40 mA. Large load: ≥40 mA.

Comment: Then Igt would not stand as max but only as Igt

Comment: Let's say you make a circuit without cooling the SCR and therefore do not want it to burn through excessive load, then you can set the gate to what the circuit is designed for and thereby secures that it does not trigger at excessive load.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40384/discussion-between-transistor-and-justme).

Comment: Not time, I'am only respond when there are answers and I'm sitting at the pc.

Comment: See the \$I_{GT}\$ update to my answer. It specifically addresses your first comment on my answer.

Comment: Too late now to read the PDF, tomorrow, but still, we're here talking about the normal way to use a SCR on which the max is what is recommended, as this is only to secure that the SCR is trigget. What I touch is an abnormal way to use an SCR, namely by just providing a trigger when the load is by Igt set limit.

Comment: Yet strange that they write Igt max when it nevertheless must be considered as min.